# Restoring a postgres8.3 backup with postgres8.4

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to restore a backup dumped from a postgres 8.3 server in a server with postgres 8.4 with this command:

```sh
pg_restore --host host --port 5432 --username username --dbname my_db /route/to/backup/b.backup --ignore-version --format=c
```

But I got this error:

> pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of
>   file

I have done a restore with another Postgres 8.3 server and it worked just fine. My box is a Linux Mint Julia.

Anyone else with this same problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses various formats for backups. What's the format of yours?

[`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgrestore.html) is only needed for backups using one of the archive file formats. The default format of backups produced with [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) is an SQL script that you can [restore via `psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE):

```sh
psql dbname < /path/to/backup
```

Start by reading the chapter ["Backup and Restore" in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup.html).